# Haskell basic Show instance for simple recursive datatype not working

Tags: haskell

i have a simple Problem. This Code looks perfectly fine to me.

```
main = do
      print("10-2")
      let a = L
      let b = E "abc" a
      print(a)
      print(b)


  data List a = L | E a (List a)

  instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
      show L = "Empty"
      show (E a list) = (show a)++ (show list)
```

But it produces following error:

```
10-2.hs:5:5:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous...
```

I cant find the Problem. Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same error you will get if you try to compile this simple program:

```
main = print []
```

What? Haskell cannot print an empty list? That's correct, it cannot. That is, unless the type of the list element is known. It is not known at this case, so compilation fails. In order to see why, run these two programs:

```
main = print ([] :: [Int])
main = print ([] :: [Char])
```

The output is different, though the only difference between these programs is the type of an empty list.

**However**, if you try this same ambiguous program in `ghci` it will print `[]` just fine!

```
Prelude> let main = print []
Prelude> main
[]
Prelude>
```

This is because `ghci` has a slightly more liberal set of [*defaulting rules*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) than `ghc`. So if you load your data type definition to `ghci` and say `print L` at the prompt, `ghci` will happily obey:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( h.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> print L
Empty
*Main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But for my List-Type the empty print is defined. It should make no difference. The L can only be from my data-type. Cant it ? the odd thing i found was:   :t L is List

Comment: @PaulOskarMayer There's no just List, there can be only List of *something*. You need to tell what i this *something* before you can print. Have you read the link I provided?

Comment: Yes i think i know what you mean. You are refering to immediate evaluation ? Is the list only filled if there is more than a constructor?

Comment: Your type is **exactly** like the built-in list, no difference whatsoever.

Comment: [this](http://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.1/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) explains it also pretty good. thanks  @ReinHenrichs

Answer (score 4):

In your function main, when you write `let a = L`, the type of `a` is just `List a0`. When the compiler tries to know which version of the `Show` instance it has to use, all types fits, because `a`'s type is not fully defined. If you delete the line `print a` however, you will see that `print b` will work, because `b`'s type can only be `List String`, and the compiler knows exactly which version of `show` it has to use.

```
main = do
  print "10-2"
  let a = L
  let b = E "abc" a
  -- print a
  print b
```

Try writing `print []` and you will see that the compiler gives you the same kind of error.

In ghci however, if you just type `print L` or `print []`, it will not prompt an error. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: It is because of GHCi's [extended defaulting rules](http://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.1/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci).

Answer (score 1):

As the others already said, you need to give your List a type, even if the data Constructor doesn't need it to create itself.

So Try out:

```
print (L :: List Int)
```

or whatever you like to just print a your String of the Show Instance of (List a)